# AWS: How to create an ELB health check endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an Elastic Beanstalk app with an application load balancer, the listener being on port 443. The LB's target group is configured to run health checks on port 443, and the check response is a 404. My app works though, and I was told I need a health check endpoint in my app. I can't find any documentation about how to do this though. What do I need to do to my app code?

Comment: is there any example to create it ? i need to create some thing similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Health Check Endpoint is any URL of your Application that

- Do not require authentication
- Do not send redirects
- Return HTTP/200 OK when your application is fine.